# Drop shadow for Drawable

Tags: android

How do i create a drop shadow to add it to a custom drawable i made using shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop shadows are automatically rendered based on the underlying image you are using for your drawable. See the Android map tutorial and notice that drop shadows are rendered for arbitrary pin images.

Answer (score 3):

http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/07/2d-graphics-with-effects_11.html